# Memory Leak in TList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am having a memory leak problem when using a TList. I am trying to populate the Tlist loop throught the populated list and use the data. The code below is only the code for populating the list not using it.

```
private
  { Private Form Variable declarations }
  GlblCancel : Boolean;
  MyPrintLst : TList;

PrintRecord = record
  PrintString1,
  PrintString2,
  PrintString3,
  PrintString4,
  PrintString5,
  PrintString6 : string;
  PrintFloat1,
  PrintFloat2,
  PrintFloat3  : Double;
end;
PrintPointer = ^PrintRecord;

Procedure TMyForm.Create;
begin
  MyPrintLst := TList.Create;
end

Procedure TMyForm.FreeTList(Var List : Tlist; Size : Integer);
Var I, Count : Integer;
begin
  Count := list.Count - 1;
  For I := Count DownTo 0 Do
     FreeMem(List[I], Size);
  List.Clear;
  List.Free;
end;

Procedure TMyForm.FormClose;
begin
  FreeTList(MyPrintLst,SizeOf(PrintRecord));
end

procedure AddToPrintList(PrintList : TList;
                         Const MyStrings : Array of String;
                         Const MyDoubles : Array of Double);
var
PrintPtr : PrintPointer;
begin
New(PrintPtr);
IF High(MyStrings) >= 0 Then
   PrintPtr^.printString1 := MyStrings[0];
 Begin
   IF High(MyStrings) >= 1 Then
    Begin
      PrintPtr^.printString2 := MyStrings[1];
      IF High(MyStrings) >= 2 Then
       Begin
         PrintPtr^.printString3 := MyStrings[2];
         IF High(MyStrings) >= 3 Then
          Begin
            PrintPtr^.printString4 := MyStrings[3];
            IF High(MyStrings) >= 4 Then
               PrintPtr^.printString5 := MyStrings[4];
             Begin
               IF High(MyStrings) >= 5 Then
                  PrintPtr^.printString6 := MyStrings[5];
             End; {>=5}
          End; {>=4}
       End; {>=3}
    End; {>=2}
 End; {>=1}
IF High(MyDoubles) >= 0 Then
 Begin
   PrintPtr^.PrintFloat1 := MyDoubles[0];
   IF High(MyDoubles) >= 1 Then
    Begin
      PrintPtr^.PrintFloat2 := MyDoubles[1];
      IF High(MyDoubles) >= 2 Then
         PrintPtr^.PrintFloat3 := MyDoubles[2];
    End;
 End;
PrintList.add(PrintPtr);
end;

Procedure TMyForm.Button1.Click;
Var EstReading : LongInt;
begin
EstReading := 0;
ClearTList(MyPrintLst,Sizeof(PrintRecord));
MyQuery.First;
While Not(MyQuery.EOF) Do
 begin
   EstReading := EstReading + 1;
   AddToPrintList(MyPrintLst, [MyQuery.FieldByName('Field1').AsString,
                               MyQuery.FieldByName('Field2').AsString, 
                               MyQuery.FieldByName('Field3').AsString, 
                               MyQuery.FieldByName*'Field4').AsString, 
                               MyQuery.FieldByName('Field5').AsString, 
                               MyQuery.FieldByName('Field6').AsString],
                               [EstReading]);
   MyQuery.Next;
 end;
end
```

Comment: Please add the leak message and all code that will produce the leak

Answer (score 12):

You are not disposing of the dynamically allocated records correctly. You record is managed, since it contain managed types, strings in this case.

Managed types, when allocated dynamically like this, need to be allocated with `New`, and deallocated with `Dispose`. Your mistake is to use `FreeMem` and not `Dispose`. The latter will dispose of the managed types within the record, the former does not. Hence your leak.

It seems likely that `ClearTList` has the same defect.

You are storing the pointers in a `TList` instance, and this type stores untyped pointers. When you dispose of each item you must cast the item back to the appropriate pointer type so that the runtime knows how to dispose of the fields within the record. So your call to `Dispose` will look like this:

```
Dispose(PrintPointer(List[I]));
```

As an aside, passing the size of the element when calling `FreeMem` is rather pointless.

To summarise:

- For unmanaged types use `GetMem/FreeMem`, or `New/Dispose`.
- For managed types use `New/Dispose`.
- Always pair these functions correctly. Always `FreeMem` with `GetMem`, always `Dispose` with `New`.

Comment: Calling Clear is pointless given that you destroy the object. Passing the list as `var` is pointless since you don't modify the variable. In any case, I think I answered the question you asked no?

Comment: I changed the freemem in the freetlist procedure and cleartlist procedure to a Dispose and I am still getting a memory leak.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. Presumably you have other defects. It's not fair to expect us to debug the rest of your code that we cannot see. Had you provided a [mcve] we could have fixed all of the code there. But you didn't. Btw it's really weird to write `Count := List.Count-1`. Use `Count` to hold, well, a count and not one fewer than the count. It's needless to make a local variable for that. Remove it.

Comment: How can I post complete Code?

Comment: It's too late. This question is a week old. I answered the question you asked. If you have a new question, make it a new question. But there's no doubt in my mind that this is the answer to the question you asked